# c# Huge memory build-up with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

Hello I am having problems with httpwebrequest, huge memory buildups when running a rather large request based program. The only real place the build up can be happening is reading the stream back after sending the request, how would I combat this or better yet set a limit to this sort of thing?

I also have various (10-15) if statements looking for various things in the body of the response but about to change them to a switch statement, although I doubt they're causing such high memory buildups I thought it'd be best to mention them. My request looks like so:

```
HttpWebResponse response = null;

            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);


                request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "max-age=0");
                request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", @"1");
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36 OPR/63.0.3368.88";


                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                string _responseData = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            catch (WebException e)
            {

            }
            catch (UriFormatException p)
            {


            }
```

As you can see my stream is read back via _responseData which I then use .contains to see if what I'm looking for is there.

Comment: Although it seems like the culprit, you should never make assumptions about memory usage. Profile it. Collecting information about .NET
memory allocation helps you identify memory leaks and provides
information about what type of objects need how much memory. Then you can take action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Set HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering to false.
- Dispose HttpWebResponse, Stream and StreamReader.

```
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

                request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "max-age=0");
                request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", @"1");
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36 OPR/63.0.3368.88";

                string _responseData;

                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                        {
                            _responseData = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {

            }
            catch (UriFormatException p)
            {

            }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Could you please explain Dispose to me a little, I wasn't aware that you needed to clean up used resources in C# like C++. If that's what it even dose.